# Regex is accepting words with symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a situation where I need to test the string if it contains a **particular word or letter** using the Javascript Regex.

Sample strings would be:

```
// In the first 3 strings, I need "C" letter to be checked in the string
C is language is required.     
We need a C language dev.
Looking for a dev who knows C!

// Keyword is Artificial Intelligence
We need looking for someone who knows Artificial Intelligence.
```

For checking the above I have created a Regex.

```
['C', 'Artificial Intelligence', 'D', 'Angular', 'JS'].forEach((item) => {
 const baseRex = /[!,.?": ]?/g;
 const finalRex = new RegExp(baseRex.source + item + baseRex.source); // /[!,.?": ]<C/D/Angular...>[!,.?": ]/

// Say checking for first iteration only. So let consider 'C'.
 console.log(finalRex.test('C is required')); // true
 console.log(finalRex.test('Looking for a dev who knows C!')); // true
 console.log(finalRex.test('We need a C language dev.')); // true
 console.log(finalRex.test('Computer needed')); // Also returns true | Which is wrong!

});
```

I won't want the words contains the letter C also get a count.

Comment: I suspect the main trouble here is to differentiate between `C` and `C++`? Try `/\bC\b(?!\+\+)/`. It will be a bit difficult to get it to work with the dynamic pattern building approach. Well, it seems you also might have a problem if you have `['Angular', 'JS', 'Angular JS']` like entries. I am afraid just `"\\b" + item + "\\b"` won't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's the exact problem. This problem looks more like an NLP and ML problem

Comment: What are your words boundaries? Can they be whitespace boundaries? Try https://ideone.com/BSUUrm

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry but nopes. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex after the concatenation with the `baseRex` is:

```
[!,.?": ]?C[!,.?": ]?
```

Notice that `[!,.?": ]?` can match 0 or 1 characters. In `Computer`, both subpatterns of `[!,.?": ]?` matches 0 characters, and `C` matches `C`, causing the whole regex to match.

Presumably, you added `?` there so that it works at the start and end of the string, where there are no characters to be matched. However, you should instead use `^` and `$` for the start and end instead. Your whole regex should be:

```
(?:[!,.?": ]|^)C(?:[!,.?": ]|$)
```

You can also replace the character class with `\W`, which means `[^0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

In fact, you don't actually need to do all of this! There is a useful 0-width matcher called "word-boundary" `\b`, which seems to be exactly the thing you want here. Your base regex can just be:

```
\b
```

It only matches the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` or between a `\W` and a `\w`.

Comment: Note that a word boundary can't always help in case there are multiple space separated entries and possibly terms with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

## for `C`

input:

```sh
C is language is required.     
We need a C language dev.
Looking for a dev who knows C!
Computer needed
invalidC should not match
```

- js regex: `(?<!\w)C(?!\w)`
- match result:

  - Chrome:

    - [image]
  - Safari: not support `look behind`

## extended to both `C` or `Artificial Intelligence`

input:

```sh
C is language is required.     
We need a C language dev.
Looking for a dev who knows C!
Computer needed
invalidC should not match
We need looking for someone who knows Artificial Intelligence.
not matchArtificial Intelligence
```

- regex: `(?<!\w)((C)|(Artificial Intelligence))(?!\w)`
- match result:

  - Chrome:

    - [image]

## Note

for more about `look ahead` and `look behind`, can refer my summary:

- one picture

  - [image]
- view online: [正则表达式详解：look ahead和look behind](https://www.processon.com/view/link/5e3a5bdbe4b06b291a60f195)

and my (Chinese) tutorial: [环视断言 · 应用广泛的超强搜索：正则表达式](https://book.crifan.com/books/super_search_regex/website/regex_syntax/look_around/)

and even all regex: [一图让你看懂和记住所有正则表达式规则](https://www.processon.com/view/link/5e3f7ca3e4b0a3daae81090f)

Comment: Why do you suggest checing for a `d` letter before `C`  with `(?<!d)`?

Comment: Anyway, that approach with `(?!\w)` or `(?<!\w)` unambiguous word boundaries won't suffice with multiple word keywords. Actually, [OP confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201845/regex-is-accepting-words-with-symbols#comment106493427_60201845) word boundaries don't work.